# Deixar o código dinâmico, em um filtro de arrays

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo deixar o meu código mais 'dinâmico' para eu não precisar adicionar um novo bloco para cada item/categoria nova que eu adicionar, é um projeto apenas para estudo. O que eu pensei era usar as funções com paramêtros mas não consegui implementar bem

```js
let animals = [{
    name: 'catOne',
    species: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'catTwo',
    species: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'dogOne',
    species: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'dogTwo',
    species: 'dog'
  },
]

let catsEl = document.getElementById('cats');
let dogsEl = document.getElementById('dogs');
let result = document.getElementById('list');

let clickCount = 0;

catsEl.addEventListener('click', function() {

  clickCount++;

  function isAnimal(animal, species) {
    return animal.species === species;
  }

  let cat = animals.filter(function(animal) {
    return isAnimal(animal, 'cat');
  });

  let lis = document.createElement('li');


  for (let i = 0; i <= clickCount; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      result.appendChild(lis).textContent = cat[j].name;

      if (clickCount > cat.length) {
        result.appendChild(lis).textContent = "No more cats";
      }
    }


  }

});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

ul#list li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button" id="cats">Cats</div>
  <div class="button" id="dogs">Dogs</div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que não fui muito claro desculpa, mas eu quero por exemplo fazer a mesma coisa do botão 'cats' no botão 'dogs' ou qualquer outro que eu adicionar, sem precisar duplicar todo meu javascript, e substituir no filter o 'cats' por  'dogs'., não quero precisar mexer no código toda vez que eu adicionar um novo "Animal" no arraye no html

Comment: Entendi, e `<ul id="list"></ul>` vai ser a mesma ? Ou quando clicar teria que ter apenas a **especie** que o usuário clicou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mesmo considerando apenas os gatos, a logica que tem está complexa e com um erro quando passa o quantidade de gatos existentes:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= clickCount; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      result.appendChild(lis).textContent = cat[j].name; //<--aqui
```

Pois o primeiro `for` vai até ao número de cliques que pode já estar fora quantidade de gatos que tem. Para além disso não precisa de um `for` para ir buscar um elemento especifico ao array.

Para apenas os gatos pode fazer desta forma:

```js
let animals = [{
    name: 'catOne',
    species: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'catTwo',
    species: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'dogOne',
    species: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'dogTwo',
    species: 'dog'
  },
];

let catsEl = document.getElementById('cats');
let dogsEl = document.getElementById('dogs');
let result = document.getElementById('list');

let clickCount = 0;

catsEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //filter só numa linha com Arrow Functions
  let cats = animals.filter(animal => animal.species === 'cat');

  if (clickCount < cats.length){ //se ainda tem elementos para por
    let lis = document.createElement('li');
    //vai buscar o gato pela posição dada pela variavel clickCount
    result.appendChild(lis).textContent = cats[clickCount].name;
  }
  else if (clickCount == cats.length){ //se está no ultimo
    let lis = document.createElement('li');
    result.appendChild(lis).textContent = "No more cats";
  }

  clickCount++;
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

ul#list li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button" id="cats">Cats</div>
  <div class="button" id="dogs">Dogs</div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Neste exemplo o `clickCount` serve como posição onde vai buscar elementos para adicionar, referente apenas a gatos. Repare que utilizei [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) no `filter` que simplificam bastante.

Agora para generalizar esta lógica para cães e gatos o melhor é criar uma função com a lógica que é comum aos dois e apenas chama-la em cada função de click. Esta função terá de receber a especie a ser adicionada, e informação referente ao `clickcount` pois terá que haver uma contagem diferente para cada especie:

```js
let animals = [{
    name: 'catOne',
    species: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'catTwo',
    species: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'dogOne',
    species: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'dogTwo',
    species: 'dog'
  },
];

let catsEl = document.getElementById('cats');
let dogsEl = document.getElementById('dogs');
let result = document.getElementById('list');

let clickCounts = [0, 0]; //agora um array de contagem de clicks por especie

function addAnimal(species, speciesIndex){//adicionar um animal leva especie e clicks
  let filteredAnimals = animals.filter(animal => animal.species === species);
  let clickCount = clickCounts[speciesIndex]; //obter os clicks para esta especie

  if (clickCount < filteredAnimals.length){
    let lis = document.createElement('li');
    result.appendChild(lis).textContent = filteredAnimals[clickCount].name;
  }
  else if (clickCount == filteredAnimals.length){ 
    let lis = document.createElement('li');
    result.appendChild(lis).textContent = "No more " + species + "s";
  }

  clickCounts[speciesIndex]++; //o incremento tem de ser no array
}

catsEl.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  addAnimal('cat',0); //click para gatos passando posição dos clicks 0
});

dogsEl.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  addAnimal('dog',1); //click para cães passando posição dos clicks 1
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

ul#list li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button" id="cats">Cats</div>
  <div class="button" id="dogs">Dogs</div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Se quiser pode também modificar o sitio onde cada especie é adicionada no html. Nesse caso teria também que modificar a função de adição de animais para receber o elemento html onde colocar o resultado.

Comment: Thanks! really helped